# SelectList checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

My application is MVC 5, trying to develop multiselect checkbox using the following:

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> AdditionalInfo = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            { 1, "Exercise" },
            { 2, "Diet" } 
        };

        public static int MapAdditionalInfo (string value)
            {
            return (from v in AdditionalInfo
                    where v.Value == value
                    select v.Key).FirstOrDefault();
            }

        public static string MapAdditionalInfo (int? value)
            {
            return (from v in AdditionalInfo
                    where v.Key == value
                    select v.Value).FirstOrDefault();
            }

        public string AdditionalInfo
            {
            get {  return MapAdditionalInfo(AdditionalInfoID); }
            set {  AdditionalInfoID = MapAdditionalInfo(value); }
            }
```

In the View:

```
   @foreach (SelectListItem item in (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Info"] )
      {
         <label><input value="@item.Value" name="AdditionalInfoID" id="AdditionalInfoID" type='checkbox' checked="@item.Selected" class="checkbox-inline" /><span class='lbl padding-4'>@item.Value </span></label>
      }
```

In the controller:

```
ViewData["Info"] = MyModel.AdditionalInfo;
```

I get the following error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]'.
```

Would appreciate your suggestions on how to solve this error or if there a example for a better way to develop a checkbox list.

Comment: Like that error suggest, you are trying to cast a dictionary into a list of `SelectListItem`, can you show us the code where you set the `ViewData["Info"]`?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do.. In the first block of code you have an ambiguous declaration of `AdditionalInfo`, one with a return signature of `string`, while the other one returns `Dictionary<int, string>`. You should be getting an Exception here, can you tell me what is going on there?

Comment: I used the first code for dropdownlist.  Now I am trying to use checkbox list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone else has the same problem, here how I solved it:
I changed foreach to:

```
 @foreach (var item in (Dictionary<int, string>)ViewData["Info"])
```

The rest of the code above is the same.